# getActivity() from non activity class Kotlin

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, fragment, android-context

I would like to go from `Fragment` to an `Activity` by clicking on an item of `Fragment`'s `RecyclerView`.  `RecyclerView` adapter is made in separate class, so in that class in the part of `setOnClickListener{}` I have to write the `Intent` part.

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{

            val intent = Intent(MainActivity.getActivity(),DetailsActivtiy::class.java)

            intent.putExtra("ImageUrl", uri)

            MainActivity.getActivity().startActivity(intent)
}
```

The problem as you might already guessed is `MainActivty.getActivity()` .
I tried the approach from `Fragment` via `onButtonClick` instead of `MainActivty.getActivity()` I wrote only `activity` and it worked perfectly but it does not work in `RecyclerView` adapter because it is non activity class. How to solve my problem?
Best, Armen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need an `Activity` to launch an `Intent`, you need a `Context`. You can get the `Context` of the viewholder's `itemView` for example, like this:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
    val context = holder.itemView.context
    val intent = Intent(context,DetailsActivtiy::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("ImageUrl", uri)
    context.startActivity(intent)
}
```

Alternatively, you could introduce a listener mechanism and notify the `Fragment` that contains the adapter that an item has been clicked, and have the `Fragment` launch the appropriate `Intent`.